# Format ggplot2 axis labels such that only numbers > 9999 have commas

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to adhere to a publication style guide whereby only numbers with 5 or more digits have commas. Have searched this but not found a way to override the defaults when using 'labels=comma.' Below is an example:

```
 require(dplyr)
 require(ggplot2)
 require(scales)

 # create mock dataframe
 temp <- mpg %>% mutate(newvar=(hwy*300))

 ggplot(temp, aes(x=cyl, y=newvar)) + geom_point() +
 scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) +
 labs(title="When using 'labels=comma'...", 
      subtitle="How format axis labels such that commas only appear for numbers > 9999?")
```

Using this example, would like the lowermost y-axis labels to read "4000", "6000" etc. Could achieve this manually but that's not worth the bother, as have many graphs with scales encompassing this range. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use an anonymous function within `scale_x_continuous`:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

# generate dummy data
x <- 9998:10004
df <- data.frame(x, y = seq_along(x))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))+
    geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(labels = function(l) ifelse(l <= 9999, l, comma(l)))
```

[image]